# why this modal didnt show up?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have this modal command, I want to make a modal shown to the user when they use the command `modal`. Is there anything wrong with the following code?

```
const { MessageActionRow, Modal, TextInputComponent } = require('discord.js');

client.on('interactionCreate', async (msg) => {
  if(msg.content === 'modal') {
        // Create the modal
        const modal = new Modal()
            .setCustomId('myModal')
            .setTitle('My Modal');
        // Add components to modal
        // Create the text input components
        const favoriteColorInput = new TextInputComponent()
            .setCustomId('favoriteColorInput')
            // The label is the prompt the user sees for this input
            .setLabel("What's your favorite color?")
            // Short means only a single line of text
            .setStyle('SHORT');
        const hobbiesInput = new TextInputComponent()
            .setCustomId('hobbiesInput')
            .setLabel("What's some of your favorite hobbies?")
            // Paragraph means multiple lines of text.
            .setStyle('PARAGRAPH');
        // An action row only holds one text input,
        // so you need one action row per text input.
        const firstActionRow = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(favoriteColorInput);
        const secondActionRow = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(hobbiesInput);
        // Add inputs to the modal
        modal.addComponents(firstActionRow, secondActionRow);
        // Show the modal to the user
        await msg.showModal(modal);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `interactionCreate` event is emitted when an interaction is created and takes a single parameter, an [`Interaction`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Interaction) that was created. It's not a `message` and has no `content` property. As `msg.content` is `undefined`, it will never match the string `"modal"` so everything inside that `if` statement is ignored.

If you want to check if someone sent a message with the word `modal` as its content, you can use the `messageCreate` event:

```js
client.on('messageCreate', async (msg) => {
  if (msg.content === 'modal') {
    // ...
```

The problem is, that `message` doesn't have a `showModal()` method, only [`CommandInteraction`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=showModal), [`ButtonInteraction`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ButtonInteraction?scrollTo=showModal), [SelectMenuInteraction](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/SelectMenuInteraction?scrollTo=showModal), etc do.

If you use the `interactionCreate` event, you'll need to check the command name, button ID, etc instead:

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
  if (interaction.isCommand() && interaction.commandName === 'modal') {
    // ...

  // OR
  if (interaction.isButton() && interaction.customId === 'modal') {
    // ...
```

Comment: it say msg.showModal is not a function

Comment: Do you use slash commands?

Comment: no i dont should i use ?

Comment: Not necessarily slash commands, but some interaction, like buttons, menus, or commands. It seems `message` doesn't have a `showModal()` method, the previous ones do.